# C++: which is the appropriate constructor to be called: the constructor or the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, copy-constructor, copy-elision

The code

```
class ElisionTest
{
public:
    int n;
    // ElisionTest(ElisionTest& other): n(other.n) {cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;}
    ElisionTest(int n): n(n) {cout<<"constructor"<<endl;}
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    ElisionTest et = 10;

}
```

prints `"constructor"` and that's fine. Now, when I uncomment the copy constructor, I get a compile time error:

```
cpp_test.cpp: In function 'int main(int, const char**)':
cpp_test.cpp:140:19: error: no matching function for call to 'ElisionTest::ElisionTest(ElisionTest)'
cpp_test.cpp:140:19: note: candidates are:
cpp_test.cpp:135:2: note: ElisionTest::ElisionTest(int)
cpp_test.cpp:135:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'ElisionTest' to 'int'
cpp_test.cpp:134:2: note: ElisionTest::ElisionTest(ElisionTest&)
cpp_test.cpp:134:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'ElisionTest' to 'ElisionTest& {aka ElisionTest&}'
```

Which probably goes on to show that here the copy constructor will be called with a temporary `ElisionTest(10)`. And since you can't have a non-const reference to a temporary, making the argument of the copy constructor a `const&` should resolve the error.

But, if I modify the copy constructor to take `const ElisionTest&` instead of `ElisionTest&`, there's no error and the output is `"constructor"` again. Why didn't it print `"copy constructor"`?

Comment: You can't have a non-const reference to a temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ElisionTest(ElisionTest& other);
```

A constructor with that signature allows the initialization of an `ElisionTest` instance through an lvalue. When you do this:

```
ElisionTest et = 10;
```

This will construct an instance of `ElisionTest` from a temporary. Your code is equivalent to:

```
ElisionTest et = ElisionTest(10);
```

This will call your constructor that takes a non-const reference and initialize `et` with that. But a non-const reference cannot be bound to a temporary. That's why we will need to add `const` to your copy-constructor so that it can support both lvalues and rvalues:

```
ElisionTest(ElisionTest const& other);
//                      ^^^^^
```

---

The reason you are seeing no output is because of something called [*copy-elision*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). The compiler can omit the call to the copy/move constructor. In GCC, you can use `-fno-elide-constructors` to turn off copy-elision.

Answer (score 1):

It outputs `"constructor"` because it needs to convert from `10` to `ElisionTest`.

It didn't also print `"copy constructor"` because it got optimized away (copy elision). That's the only possible optimization that is allowed to alter the observable behavior of a program.

Comment: so you're saying that if elision was off, then the output will be `"constructor\ncopy constructor\n"`?